# Why does sorting not happen to the reports when the reports in development is migrated to stage?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I developed my reports in development server with months sorting done. But once these reports are moved to stage, the sorting of the months is not happening. There should not have any change when I migrate report from development to stage. But here it is happening for sort.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Did anyone face this issue?

Thanks

Niki

Answer (score 0):

I dint face the same issue. But i faced a issue something similar to what your talking about. In my report i would custom sort the months and save it. Once the variable used changes then the sorting goes off. i have to resort them again. I dint find a way yet to solve that.